# How to get MUC room list which a user already participated?

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, asmack, multiuserchat

I am using MUC for group chat using smack. i want to get list of MUC rooms which user already participated like whatsapp.

Using belove code, I get only rooms which user joined but i need to get the all groups which I already became a member.

Here is my code :

```
 List<EntityBareJid> joinedRoomes = manager.getJoinedRooms(conn);

            for (EntityBareJid jRoomName : joinedRoomes) {

                Log.e("Group Chat : Joined room = " , jRoomName.toString());

            }
```

Anyone help me?

Also i want to add avatar image for MUC group. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no command to get the list of rooms where an account is member/admin/owner... There is only a command to get the list of affiliations of a specific room.

> Also i want to add avatar image for MUC group. how can i do that?

A room does not have vcard, so it has no place to store the image. But it has a "Description" field, where you can put the URL of the avatar image, and then modify clients to read that URL and display the image as the room avatar.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way to get group members and detail

```
 public static List<String> getRoomInfo(String grp_id) {
    List<String> jids = new ArrayList<>();
    try {


        EntityBareJid mucJid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom(grp_id + "@" + Constants.GRP_SERVICE);


        mucChatManager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(MyApplication.connection);
        mucChat = mucChatManager.getMultiUserChat(mucJid);

        RoomInfo info = mucChatManager.getRoomInfo(mucJid);


        LogM.e("Number of occupants:" + info.getOccupantsCount());
        LogM.e("Room Subject:" + info.getSubject());

        Log.e(TAG, "members " + mucChat.getMembers().size());

        List<Affiliate> affiliatesMembers = mucChat.getMembers();


        Log.e(TAG, "members1 " + affiliatesMembers.size());
        for (Affiliate affiliate : affiliatesMembers) {
            Log.e(TAG, "members: Jid:" + affiliate.getJid()

            );
            if (affiliate.getJid() != null) {
                jids.add(affiliate.getJid().toString());
            }
        }
        return jids;

    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException | XMPPException.XMPPErrorException | InterruptedException | XmppStringprepException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Group Error : " + e.getMessage());

    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Group Error2 : " + e.getMessage());

    }
    return jids;
}
```